# How to Initialize a Reusable NSView Built in Interface Builder (Backed by a Xib) Without a ViewController

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, xamarin.mac

I am trying to make a reusable view that I can programmatically instantiate multiple copies of within a superview. However, I would like to handle the constraints and basic layout of this reusable view within Interface Builder. For my superview, I have an `NSViewController` subclass, an `NSView` subclass, and a xib file. Within the `ViewDidLoad` of my ViewController, I have code like this to instantiate the children views:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    var exampleView = new NSView();

    View.AddSubview(exampleView);
    View.AddConstraints(CreateExampleViewConstraints(exampleView, View));

    NSView lastView = null;
    foreach(var item in ExampleCollection)
    {
            var reuseableView = ReusableView.Create(item);
            reuseableView.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

            exampleView.AddSubview(reuseableView);
            var xPosConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.Create(reuseableView, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, exampleView, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, 1, 0);
            NSLayoutConstraint yPosConstraint = null;
            if(lastView != null)
            {
                yPosConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.Create(reuseableView, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, lastView, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 1, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                yPosConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.Create(reuseableView, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, exampleView, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, 1, 0);
            }
            var widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.Create(reuseableView, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, exampleView, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, 1, 0);
            var heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.Create(reuseableView, NSLayoutAttribute.Height, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, 1, 142);
            exampleView.AddConstraint(xPosConstraint);
            exampleView.AddConstraint(yPosConstraint);
            exampleView.AddConstraint(widthConstraint);
            exampleView.AddConstraint(heightConstraint);

            lastView = reuseableView;
        }
    }

    if(lastView != null)
    {
        var bottomPinConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.Create(exampleView, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, lastView, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 1, 0);
        exampleView.AddConstraint(bottomPinConstraint);
    }
}
```

The constraints are unimportant for the issue I am trying to solve. `ReusableView` is a subclass of `NSView` that has 3 `NSTextField` outlets named `TitleLabel`, `DateLabel`, and `LocationLabel`:

```
public partial class ReusableView : AppKit.NSView
{
    string _title;
    string _date;
    string _location;

    public ReusableView(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
    }

    [Export("initWithCoder:")]
    public ReusableView(NSCoder coder) : base(coder)
    {
    }

    public static ReusableView Create(ExampleDependency dependency)
    {
        var model = dependency ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dependency));
        NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNibNamed(nameof(ReusableView), null, out var array);
        var view = NSArray.FromArray<NSObject>(array).OfType<ReusableView>().FirstOrDefault();
        view.Initialize(model);
        return view;
    }

    private void Initialize(ExampleDependency dependency)
    {
        _title = dependency.name;
        _date = dependency.date;
        _location = $"{dependency.eventCity}, {dependency.eventState}";
    }

    public void UpdateControls()
    {
        TitleLabel.StringValue = _title;
        DateLabel.StringValue = _date;
        LocationLabel.StringValue = _location;
    }
}
```

The problem I am running into is: at no time during the lifecycle methods of the ViewController prior to display are the IBOutlets of ReusableView hooked up/not null. As you can see, I have a public method called `UpdateControls()` to try to set the initial values of the labels based on the private fields that are initialized during `Create()`. The `Create()` method does successfully load the xib and return an instance of `ReusableView`; I can even see the views and the placeholder values at runtime. However, I have tried calling `UpdateControls()` during the `AwakeFromNib()` and the `ViewWillAppear()` methods of the superview's view controller, but always get a null reference exception because none of the outlets are apparently instantiated yet.

I could obviously completely programmatically create ReusableView and set my constraints for the controls in code, but I'm trying to leverage interface builder. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to get this to work without adding a View Controller for my Reusable view. In Xamarin, I used the `Mac > View with Controller` template and laid out all of my constraints in the generated xib file. Then, in the code I changed:

```
var reuseableView = ReusableView.Create(item);
reuseableView.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

exampleView.AddSubview(reuseableView);
```

to:

```
var reusableViewController = new ReuseableViewController(item);
var reuseableView = reusableViewController.View;
reuseableView.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

exampleView.AddSubview(reuseableView);
```

Accessing the strongly typed `View` property on the `ReuseableViewController` ensures that my xib will be loaded and outlets connected. In the `ReuseableViewController` code, I have the following:

```
// Call to load from the XIB/NIB file
public ReuseableViewController(ExampleDependency dependency) : base("ReuseableViewController", NSBundle.MainBundle)
{
    _dependency = dependency;
}

public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    if(_dependency != null)
    {
        TitleLabel.StringValue = _dependency.name;
        DateLabel.StringValue = _dependency.date;
        LocationLabel.StringValue = $"{_dependency.eventCity}, {_dependency.eventState}";
    }
}
```

I'm not 100% satisfied with this answer, since I feel like the View Controller shouldn't be necessary for code reuse, so if anyone else has a better answer, please go ahead and respond.